# How to implement "git checkout -- <pathspec>" in libgit2sharp?

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I try to implement "git checkout -- <pathspec>" in libgit2sharp.
The semantic of the git command is:

> "git checkout [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…​"
>   Overwrite paths in the working tree by replacing with the contents in the index or in the  (most often a commit). When a  is given, the paths that match the  are updated both in the index and in the working tree.

In my case no <tree-ish> is given.

I create an empty file and add the new file to the index (git add).
Then i do some changes in the file.
After running "git checkout -- <pathspec>" the file is empty and still present in the index.

I implemented this with libgit2sharp using:

`repository.Checkout(repository.Head.Tip.Tree, new string[] { sPath }, checkoutOptions);`

As a result the index is updated too. Which means the file does no longer exist.

Any ideas?